# Prove that there is an $n$ with $x_0-\frac 1n\le x\le x_0-\frac 1{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> If $x_0-\frac 1k<x<x_0$ we have $x_0-\frac 1n\le x\le x_0-\frac 1{n+1}$ for some $n\ge k$.

How to prove this?

(Here $n$ and $k$ are natural numbers, all others are reals.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0 = x +\epsilon$ and $\epsilon >0$, so we now have that $ x+\epsilon -\frac{1}{k} < x < x+\epsilon$. which is true if $\frac{1}{k} > \epsilon$,

Now we want to prove that its true for $x +\epsilon -\frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq x+\epsilon -\frac{1}{n+1}$. for some $n\geq k$. for the upper bound its true whenever $\epsilon \geq \frac{1}{n+1}$ and from the lower bound its true whenever $\epsilon \leq \frac{1}{n}$ so $ \frac{1}{\epsilon}-1 \leq n \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ so $n = \lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon} \rfloor$ is valid and its the only valid solution(since you are asking for "there is" then this solution is sufficient).

Recall that we have $\frac{1}{k} > \epsilon$ so $k \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ so $n \geq k$.